# Как настроить модель как первичный автоинкрементный ключ в EF Core с помощью Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

В проекте с ef core в модели использую в качестве первичного ключа объект, в котором содержится сам Id.

Пример модели:

```
 public class Catalog
{
    public Catalog()
    {
    }

    public CatalogId Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Пример класса первичного ключа:

```
public class CatalogId
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public CatalogId(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Настроил ef core так что он понимает как мапить объект:

```
        builder.Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.Id,
                v => new CatalogId(v))
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
```

Но при этом не получается записать данные в базу. Ругается что первичный ключ нулевой. Заглянул в базу, в таблице объект не создался как автоинкрементный, столбец создался как обычный первичный ключ.

Проверил миграции, для обычных моделей Id генерируется следующим образом:

```
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")
```

В моем случае с классом `Catalogs`, отсутствует  `Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")`, добавление аннотации в миграцию вручную не помогло, т.к. в таком случае при вставке данных модели с `Id = 0` Ef Core воспринимает как попытку вставить Id в автоинкрементное поле.

**Как через Fluent Api настроить Ef Core так, чтобы поле было автоинкрементным первичным ключом?**

P.S: Ef core версии 3.1.6

P.S.S.: Использовать аннотации по типу `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` не могу, класс в домене. Создать DTO и мапить доменную сущность в обычную, очень усложняет реализацию.

Comment: [Explicitly configuring value generation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api#explicitly-configuring-value-generation) - возможно, это поможет. Смотреть вкладку Fluent API. Метод `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пробовал, не вставляет автоматически значения